# How to install SharePoint 2007 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine?

Tags: 2007

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise. How can I install SharePoint 2007 on my machine / which version should I used? I have tried SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise SP1, but the installation failed (error message: version not compatible with OS).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/10/02/install-sharepoint-server-2007-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) on MSDN on how to do it in Win 2008 RC2. In short it needs SP2 Slipstreamed as Michael Mentioned +1

Answer (score 10):

You have to use SharePoint 2007 with SP2 slipstreamed into it.